# Customize style of Directory Listing in Jetty Server

Tags: jetty

I am wondering if there is a way to customize the structure/style of the directory listing generated by a Jetty server.

The app I'm working with runs on Tomcat, and has a xsl file that handles the listing there, but the testing environment runs on Jetty which renders a completely different page structure.

I'm hoping there is a way to customize the page served by Jetty so that it matches the one generated from the xsl file in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: this is only true for directory listings produced by the DefaultServlet on Jetty (all other directory listings you see from a Jetty server are not produced by Jetty itself, but rather by some 3rd party library)*

The output of the directory listings provided by the Jetty Server can be customized with a CSS only.

Make a `jetty-dir.css` and Jetty in the root of your webapp and Jetty will use it.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. Thank you for confirming.